# Ckeditor missing buttons

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm using CKeditor as the Wysiwyg container. I configured it to show the full toolbar but when the user tries to edit it does not show the buttons configured.
I'm using the last version of the module available for drupal 7 and jquery 1.7.
Some buttons as iframe or letter size are not showing up.
What can I do to solve this.
Best regards
Eduardo

Comment: Most probably the wrong text-format configured as default...

Comment: Could you explain me a little bit more your idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is showing for you (user one or admin) but not someone else logged in, it could be permissions.

I would create a test account with the same permissions as the person having issues. Do you see the ckeditor toolbar while logged into the test account?

If that is working, try the solution mentioned [here.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104110/ckeditor-not-showing-toolbar-in-drupal)

Comment: Hi conorb,   Thanks for your answer but I can see the ckeditor toolbar but some of the buttons are not available. I made a theme update. Before I was able to see all buttons but now I can't. In the confirguration I can see them but in edit mode they are not there (for example iframe, the size of the letters) And they are important for my users. If yoyu can point me the way I apreciate it . Best regards Eduardo

Comment: Hey Eduardo, what console errors are you getting when the button is not appearing if any?

Comment: I'm having this info in the console: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.     But I already cheged the jquery version but the problem remains....

Comment: Hey Eduardo,  hmmm. okay- what theme did you update to? I had a similar issue when I changed a ckEditor theme- I changed the skin to Moono and it fixed my issue.

Take a look at the issue here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2094799 and see if that helps you out- let me know.